# Name cannot be updated and picture is deleted after editing

Tags: php

I have two problems:

1. Name cannot be updated
2. Profile picture is deleted (the exist one) even though I did not upload a new one. I have no problem in uploading image though.

[image: this is where I should edit my profile.]

[image: i DIDN'T upload a new image but the picture is deleted AFTER I clicked Save]

Below is the code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $target_dir = "images/staff/";
        $target_dir = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["new_profilepicture"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk=1;

        if (file_exists($target_dir . $_FILES["new_profilepicture"]["name"])) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
        if ($uploadOk==0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    } 
    else { 
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["new_profilepicture"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) {
        $imageup = $target_dir;
        echo "<img src='" . $imageup . "' />";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
        $_var1 = $_POST['new_name'];
        $_var2 = $_POST['new_email'];
        $_var3 = $_POST['new_password'];
        $_var4 = $_POST['new_contactno'];
        $_var5 = $_POST['new_icno'];
        $_var6 = $_POST['new_address'];
        $_var7 = $_POST['new_status'];
        $_var8 = $imageup;

        $query1 =   "UPDATE staff
                            SET StaffName='$_var1', StaffEmail='$_var2', StaffPassword='$_var3', StaffContactNo='$_var4', StaffICNo='$_var5', StaffAddress='$_var6', StaffStatus='$_var7', StaffProfilePicture='$_var8'
                            WHERE StaffID='$staffID'";

        $success = mysql_query($query1);//is mysql query working?

            if($success){
                $oldprofilepicture = $staff['StaffProfilePicture'];
                if(file_exists($oldprofilepicture)){
                    unlink($oldprofilepicture);//delete now
                }
            header('location:staff_profile.php');
            }
        }
```

Below is the line where a new name is entered.

```
<tr>
                <td width="170">Full Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="new_name" size="30" value="<?php echo $staffname ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: `$oldprofilepicture = $staff['StaffProfilePicture'];` isn't that the new profile picture? you should have deleted the picture before update. Use a select query before update and use that oldprofilepicture.

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_` function is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. I would suggest using [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the image, create a hidden input field with the same value as from the database, e.g.:

```
<input type="hidden" value="/path/to/img.ext" name="old-image" />
```

Before this line:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["new_profilepicture"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) {
```

Add:

```
$imageup = $_POST['old-image'];
```

Of course you need to do validation on the `$_POST` data. I've left it out of the above example.

This will set the default value for the image as the saved version. If you upload a new image, then that will override `$imageup` with the name path details :)

Regarding the name not changing, I cannot see where the value for `$staffId` is being set?